# How can I see all the interfaces a coclass implements in COM?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, excel, com

Specifically I want to see all interfaces in the MSHTML library.  I can't decompile it because it's written in a native language

Comment: Take `C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.tlb`, open it in [OLE/COM Object Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx). Or add it as a reference to your VBA project - I seem to remember VBA has a built-in object viewer. Or, read the fine manual - MSHTML is thoroughly documented.

Comment: And even so, an object may implement more interfaces than the declared set.  For that, only further documentation and decompilation can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the dll or the tlb file into any COM Interface viewer you will be able to see all the Interfaces it declares.  COM Interfaces are public so you don't need to decompile they are designed to be easily read.

There is a list here of [Type Library Viewers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680581(v=vs.85).aspx), or you could look up the documentation for [MSHTML online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801968(v=vs.85).aspx)